# How to insert same item into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to insert same item into nested array. Here is my input element.

```
var myData1 = [{data1: 1},{data2:2}];
var myData2 = [{data1: 1},{data2:2}];
var myData3 = [{data1: 1},{data2:2}];

var key = [myData1, myData2, myData3];

var myVale = {
    someValue :"SomeValue",
    myData: [],
    myVal: []

}
```

ANd this is my expected o/p

```
var myVale = {
    someValue :"SomeValue",
    myData: myData1,
    myVal:[{someValue :"SomeValue",
           myData: myData2,
           myVal : [{
                someValue :"SomeValue",
                myData: myData3,
            }]
          }]
}
```

What I am trying here is

```
for(var i=0; i<key.length;i++){ 
    myVale.myVal.push(myVale);
    myVale.myData.push(key[i])
}
```

But here I am not getting an expected result. The output is going into loop. Any suggestion how I can get that?

Comment: `myData1`, `myData2` and `myData3` as different variables... Shouldn't it be a single array?

Comment: Seems like nothing went wrong.

Comment: @GrafiCode You mean like this : `data = [{myData1 : [{data1: 1},{data2:2}]},{myData2 = [{data1: 1},{data2:2}]}, {myData3 = [{data1: 1},{data2:2}]}]`

Comment: @Ragulan myVal and myData are adding three times. Not like the thing which expecting in output.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the input to ensure it is working as expected

```js
    var myData1 = [{data11: 1},{data12:2}];
    var myData2 = [{data21: 1},{data22:2}];
    var myData3 = [{data31: 1},{data32:2}];
    
    var key = [myData1,myData2,myData3];
    
    var myVale = {};
    var index = 0;
    function formatJSON(key, index) {
        var tempVale = {};
        tempVale.someValue = "SomeValue"+index;
        tempVale.myData = key[index];
        if(++index >= key.length)
            return tempVale;
        tempVale.myVal = formatJSON(key, index);
    
        return tempVale;
    }
    myVale = formatJSON(key, index);
    console.log(myVale);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myVale));
```